# Remove "optional" keyword while displaying string - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

I am working on a movies app and it displays release date as part of the movie details on table view cell. Below is the code:

```
let date = movieDetail.releaseDate as String
let releaseDateText = NSLocalizedString("release date", comment: "Release date label text")
let tbaText = NSLocalizedString("tba", comment: "TBA text")
releaseDateLabel.text = "\(releaseDateText): \(String(describing: date != "" ? Date.getMMMddyyyyDateFormat(date) : "\(tbaText)" ))"
```

With this, I do see the date on the screen as Optional("Jan 07,2018"). I just want to display the date without optional keyword and parenthesis. Am not able to figure out what is causing "Optional" keyword to show up.

Part of my app:
[image]

Comment: And yet this has been explained so many times here... why not search before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
releaseDateLabel.text = "\(releaseDateText): \(String(describing: date != "" ? Date.getMMMddyyyyDateFormat(date) : "\(tbaText)" ))"
```

with

```
releaseDateLabel.text = "\(releaseDateText): \(date != "" ? Date.getMMMddyyyyDateFormat(date)! : "\(tbaText)" ))
```

for safty try

```
if date != "" {
    if let str = Date.getMMMddyyyyDateFormat(date) {
       releaseDateLabel.text = "\(releaseDateText): \(str)"
     }
}
else {
       releaseDateLabel.text = "\(releaseDateText): \(tbaText)"
}
```

Comment: I had that initially, but I was seeing this warning "String interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value; did you mean to make this explicit? Use 'String(describing:)' to silence this warning"

Comment: if this **getMMMddyyyyDateFormat** return optional unwrap it or use if let ,  see edit

Comment: I had tried if let, but was seeing some other errors with it. I had to unwrap the value that I receive from getMMMddyyyyDateFormat, so adding '!' post that solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I added the safe way to avoid unexpected crashes ,  nil coalescing operator **??** is a 3rd option also